# PHP echo image from spesific URL query parameter

Tags: php

How do I show photos from an external url parameter via url. And display the mime type image.
Example

http://www.rotena.lt/popup.php?image=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-l1s6UFGlK6o/VlmxFbaN43I/AAAAAAAADOU/yZWSg4-TtNQ/s640/remove%2Blabels%2Bpermanently.png

Description:

popup.php = php script
?image=http:// = url query for load
1.bp.blogspot.com/-l1s6UFGlK6o/VlmxFbaN43I/AAAAAAAADOU/yZWSg4-TtNQ/s640/remove%2Blabels%2Bpermanently.png = source of external images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the image link first

```
$url = $_GET['image'];
```

then just echo it out:

```
<img src="<? echo $url; ?>">
```

can use `<?= ?>` if you have them enabled in your `php.ini` and can even just echo out the `GET` variable in src but for now this will just do